# Project upgraded from Xcode 5 to 6 won't compile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I upgraded from Xcode 5 to 6 and now my code won't compile.  I found some similar issues from 3 to 4 but none for the newest version.

Here is the error I'm getting.

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there a common fix for this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try deleting your derived data?

Comment: Tried this as well.  No luck.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I think I'm running into a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which was fixed by running clean (in menu under product/clean).

Comment: No luck here.  I cleaned successfully, but it's still failing to compile.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1:**
Oh found issue with your build settings.

**1.** 
How come the test file is linked with your project?
Just remove the "XCTest.Framework" file from Project Navigator > Targets > 'Project Name' > Build Phases.
Then, "Product" (drop-down) > Clean. Did it for me!

**2.** 
Also 
Project > Targets > 'Project Name' > Build Phases > Compile Sources
XCTest should not be included in your regular application code. So you should remove any Test Source from the Compile sources and move to Test Target.

---

You should update your 'Build active architecture only' to NO in Build Settings.

Restart Xcode and clean build.

Should work fine.

Comment: Changed to NO in the build settings, restarted, and cleaned.  Still failing on compile.

Comment: Updated the solution above.

Comment: I removed from that build phases page. I've done that and cleaned.  Still not compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to remove the XCTest framework from your project file and re-add it from the iOS frameworks.

Seems odd that your iOS project somehow got linked to a Mac framework during the upgrade.